# HTML CSS vertical align in LI

Tags: html, css

```
li{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px; 
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

It's my vertical buttons menu, and i want to have my text lying on bottom of the 96x96 squares.

Comment: Add `display: table-cell` instead of `float: left`

Answer (score 1):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MqpdP/1/)**

**css**

```
li {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border:1px solid red;
    list-style-type:none;
}
li img{
    display:inline-block;
        height:96px;
    width:96px;
}
li span{
    display:block;

}
```

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="" alt="img"/> <span>1</span></li>
    <li><img src="" alt="img"/> <span>1</span></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you meant is that you want your text inside the links to be aligned inside of the 96x96 box at the bottom.

If I am correct in that assumption, you can assign a `line-height` to the `li` element (a block element) that is equal to its height (`96px`). Then you can assign a smaller `line-height` (such as `20px`) to the child link itself (an inline element) and use `vertical-align: bottom;` on the link.

[JSFiddle example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/2GsTN/)